# Conda: how to hide most of the path when environment is active?

Tags: conda

When I activate an environment `my-env`, my terminal additionally shows `(/my/path/to/my-env) user:`. Is there a way to hide part of the path in `/my/path/to/my-env`? For instance, just showing `(/my-env/) user:`? As it is it's super long :)

Comment: How did you create the environment?

Comment: @darthbith `conda env create -f myenv.yml -p my-env`

Comment: If you used the `-p` option, then conda always shows the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command:

> conda config --set env_prompt '({name})'

This will change your shell prompt so that only the name of the active environment is displayed, as in the following example:

> ({env-name})user@server:/>

You can find more related options in the official documentation:
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment